# How can I run function for each element in different time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know, how can I run one function for each element I select. This is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $(".line").each(function() {
    var dot = $(this).find('.dot');
    setTimeout(function () {
      moveDot(dot);
    }, 250);
  });
});
```

It could run `moveDot()` for each element (every after 250ms), but now, all elements starts at the same time. Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wHgLy/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `index` to `setTimeout()`. It would increment for each element in the loop, and thus add to the delay.

```
$(function() {
  $(".line").each(function(index) {
    var dot = $(this).find('.dot');
    setTimeout(function () {
      moveDot(dot);
    }, index * 250);
  });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHgLy/1/)**

Comment: Ok.. i checked this fiddle and it look's good. But i found something that i thought i should bring in notice to all you guies. Just out of curiosity.. go to Fiddle link and run the animation. It will look fine. Now click on another tab and again click on Fiddle link, you will see most of the animated due get's align...I dont know why???

Answer (score 2):

Use the indices:

```
$(".line").each(function(i) {
   var dot = $(this).find('.dot');
   setTimeout(function () {
     moveDot(dot);
   }, ++i * 250);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d59c7/

Answer (score 2):

Multiply with each `index`

```
$(".line").each(function(i) {
   var dot = $(this).find('.dot');
   setTimeout(function () {
     moveDot(dot);
   }, 250 * i+1);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wHgLy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use random function javascript

```
(function() {
  $(".line").each(function() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) + 1);
    var dot = $(this).find('.dot');
    setTimeout(function () {
      moveDot(dot);
    }, x);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer like this as one of solution:

```
 function moveDot(elm,index) {
  elm.animate({left: '370px'}, {duration: 3000*index, queue: false, done: function() {
  elm.animate({left: '0px'}, {duration: 3000*index, queue: false, done: function() {
  moveDot(elm,index)
    }});
  }}); 
 }

  $(function() {
   $(".line").each(function(i) {
   var dot = $(this).find('.dot');
   setTimeout(function () {
     moveDot(dot,++i);
   }, 250);
  });
  });
```

Comment: Nope, that will animate `.dot` slower and slower by each one and I need same animation duration on every `.dot`.

Comment: Thanks debute. I'll try to correct my code later but i am little curious about something i found weird.Please checked above fiddle suggested and it look's good. But i found something that i thought i should bring in notice to all you guies. Just out of curiosity.. go to Fiddle link and run the animation. It will look fine. Now click on another tab and again click on Fiddle link, you will see most of the animated due get's align...I dont know why???

Comment: You don't have to edit your code later, I already have solution by Shaunak D as answer above. Yea, I know that bug with tabs, I don't know what it could be, but I already get everything I wanted.